# android system update in custom rom

Tags: custom-roms, ota-update

I am using a custom rooted android device (not used by anyone else) which comes with android 4.1.2 custom rom.

Suddenly I received an auto update notification and everything was erased... it was a total mess...

1. Where does my device get the link to download the update from?
2. How do I disable the auto update?

Even if those things are totally differ from one device to another, I would be very glad to receive a few leads...

thank you.